# Which version of Sqoop works with Hadoop 1.0.4?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I'm using hadoop 1.0.4 and hive 0.9.0
can any one suggest which version of Sqoop we can configure?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using latest Sqoop version 1.4.2. You can get the bits from [official mirror](http://www.apache.org/dist/sqoop/1.4.2/). Please make sure to download file ending with "hadoop-1.0.0.tar.gz" that contains binary artifact compatible with your Hadoop release.